# Make sign up buttons consistent

Tags: bug, design, sign-up

This bug is reproduceable on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/#

This:

[image]

From achievements. And this:

[image]

From inbox are not consistent.

I suggest to keep them consistent.

Comment: They both look the same on my computer in incognito mode (as your second one), Firefox dev edition 50.0a2 on Linux

Comment: Both buttons same here as well. Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, Win 7. It'd be better if you add your browser information etc.

Comment: different for me, running on Windows 10 with Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)

Comment: Both are the same for me in Chrome 44.0.2403.157 m, Win 7

Comment: @Lafexlos This bug is reproduceable on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/#